# Creating variable width carousel issue using slick.js library

Tags: jquery, slick.js

This is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6wfG/92/.

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.variable-width').slick({

      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      variableWidth: true,
     // autoplay: true
    });

    $('.next-slide').click(function(){
        $("#slide-custom").slickNext();
    });
    $('.prev-slide').click(function(){
        $("#slide-custom").slickPrev();
    });
});
```

this is the html part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider variable-width" id ="slide-custom">
    <div style="width:500px; height:100px;border:1px solid black;">1</div>
    <div style="width:600px; height:100px;border:1px solid black;">2</div>
    <div style="width:200px; height:100px;border:1px solid black;">3</div>
     <div style="width:600px; height:100px;border:1px solid black;">4</div>
    <div style="width:400px; height:100px;border:1px solid black;">5</div>
    <div style="width:700px; height:100px;border:1px solid black;">6</div>
</div>
<button class="prev-slide">prev</button>
<button class="next-slide" >next</button>
```

As you can see in the fiddle for some reason the next and prev button are generated, in my site there aren't. so i created manually and i want to assign the `nextSlick` and `prevSlick`, but they are not working. WHY ?

**UPDATE CONSOLE RESULT**:[image]

Comment: are there any errors on the console, if you open dev tools in chrome? The next and previous buttons should be showing and you shouldn't need to define them manually. Are some styles on causing the next and previous buttons to be hidden on your site?

Comment: I updated my post please check it :)

Comment: But even the next and prev button aren't generated in the html code. I searched for it ctrl+u

Comment: those errors certainly seem to be an issue, jQuery not defined and slickNext not a function. I would strip back your page on your website to similar to the jsFiddle example, obviously on a test page, and see if you can introduce the rest of the page functionality to see what has caused the issue, also make sure jQuery and slick.js are on your page, there might be an issue with the includes. Check the Sources tab in Chrome dev tools, are they being loaded okay?

Comment: I managed it out the errors. I should include the slick-next class